# Verifying that open balls in the plane form a basis for a topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I am trying to verify an example in Munkres's Topology of a basis for a topology. He considers the collection $\mathcal{B}$ of all circular regions / interiors of circles in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. I assume he is considering $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard topology, but he doesn't say exactly.

I may be misunderstanding the concept of a basis, because the set of interiors of circles essentially *is* the standard topology on the plane, excluding the empty set and the entirety of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so it seems peculair to take that a basis. Some clarification on this would be helpful. Another thing I don't fully understand is the second condition for a basis: If $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ for two basis elements $B_1$, $B_2$, then there exists $B_3$ such that $x \in B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$. Can I assume that Munkres requires $B_1 \neq B_2 \neq B_3$?

Onto the proof:

> We first need to check that for each $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$, there exists $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B$. Given such an $x$, we can take any $r > 0$. Then $B_r (x) \in \mathcal{B}$ by definition, so the first condition is satisfied. Second, given open balls $B_{\epsilon} (x)$ and $B_{\delta} (y)$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $\epsilon, \delta > 0$ and $z \in B_{\epsilon} (x) \cap B_{\delta} (y)$, we must prove there is a third a basis element contained in this intersection. We have $d(x,z) < \epsilon$ and $d(y,z) < \delta$. Set $r = \min\{\epsilon - d(x,z), \delta - d(y,z)\}$, and consider $B_r (z)$. Given $p \in B_r (z)$, we have:
> \begin{align*}
> d(p,x) \leq d(p,z) + d(z,x) < r + d(z,x) \leq (\epsilon - d(x,z) + d(x,z) = \epsilon \\
> d(p,y) \leq d(p,z) + d(z,y) < r + d(z,y) \leq (\delta - d(y,z)) + d(z,y) = \delta
> \end{align*}
> So $p \in B_{\epsilon} (x) \cap B_{\delta} (y)$, so $B_{r} (z) \subset B_{\epsilon} (x) \cap B_{\delta} (y)$.

How does this look?

Comment: You don't have to assume $B_1,B_2,B_3$ are different, it's in fact irrelevant to the proof.

Comment: That seems to almost trivialize the definition, though, unless Im misunderstanding. If $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, then $B_1 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$ if I take $B_3 = B_1$. Is that allowed?

Comment: Yes, that is also allowed. For many bases we can always take $B_3= B_1 \cap B_2$ (e.g. the standard product base has this). The statement is just the existence of $B_3$ for any triple $(B_1,B_2,x)$ that applies. It makes the definition intuitive and simple.

Comment: Is there every a case where this isn't satisfied, though? It seems that the implication will always follow from the truth of the antecedent If $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ for sets $B_1, B_2$, then always we can take $B_3 = B_1 \cap B_2$. It doesn't seem like the condition is really saying anything.

Comment: $B_1 \cap B_2$ need not be a set in the (**pregiven!**) $\mathcal B$ at all so that argument is nonsense. Look at your own argument: you needed an argument to find the third ball.

Comment: What the conditions say: if $\mathcal{B}^\cup$ is the set of all unions of subfamilies of $\mathcal B$ then $X \in \mathcal{B}^\cup$ and $\forall B_1,B_2 \in \mathcal{B}: B_1 \cap B_2 \in \mathcal{B}^\cup$. It then easily follows  $\mathcal{B}^\cup$ is a topology.

Comment: That makes much more sense. I was going to ask next why I can't just take $B_1 = B_3$ or $B_2 = B_3$, but the open-ball example solves that geometrically. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a slight misunderstanding. You have correctly proved that $\mathcal B$ is a basis for a topology on $\mathbb R^2$. Clearly this topology is what is usually denoted as **the standard topology on $\mathbb R^2$**, but it is **not the purpose** of this example to introduce the concept of the standard topology on $\mathbb R^2$. Its purpose is just to give an example illustrating the concept of a basis.

The standard topology on $\mathbb R$ is introduced in the definiton on p. 81. The standard topology on $\mathbb R^2$ is introduced in Example 1 on p. 87 as the product topology on $\mathbb R^2 = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$. It is then a theorem that the standard topology on $\mathbb R^2$ is the same as the topology generated by $\mathcal B$. See Theorem 20.3. But note that Munkres does not define the notion of "standard topology" on $\mathbb R^n$ for $n > 2$. I think this is a shortcoming; the standard topology on $\mathbb R^n$ is the *Euclidean topology* which is induced by the Euclidean metric. This topology can be desribed in various alternative forms; see Theorem 20.3.

That said, in the second condition we do need to assume that $B_1 \ne B_2$. If $B_1 = B_2 = B$, then we can take $B_3 = B$ for all $x \in B_1 \cap B_2 = B$. This is just a trivial case. However, if $B_1 \ne B_2$, then $B_1 \cap B_2$ is a proper subset of both $B_i$, and for $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ we need a new element $B_3 \in \mathcal B$ (distinct from $B_1, B_2$) to get $x \in B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$.

It is of course possible (but not guaranteed)  that $B_1 \cap B_2 \in \mathcal B$; then we may take $B_3 = B_1 \cap B_2$ for all $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$. This happens when $B_1 = B_2$.

Answer (score 0):

In §13, examples 1,2 (2nd ed.), Munkres notes that the two bases of open interiors of ractangles and open interiors of circles both form bases of a topology on $\Bbb R^2$ and that they in fact give the same topology (in ex. 4) because inside each circle we can find a smaller rectangle and vice versa (this is before open balls or metrics are introduced).

In §15, ex 1 he introduces the **standard topology** on $\Bbb R^2$ as the product topology of $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$, which turn out also to be the open rectangle areas (as $\Bbb R$ has a base of open intervals).

So I don't see any exercise or work to be done. He just gave two alternative descriptions of the same topology. You are working in a metric context and that is not yet relevant at this stage of the book. Exercise 1 in §20 might be what you mean, where metrics are introduced that also give the same topology on $\Bbb R^2$ (and even $\Bbb R^n$, which must also have the product topology as its standard one, in analogy). The circular regions correspond to the $2$-metric and the rectangles to the $\infty$ or sup metric.